# Verificar si API retorna o no un valor

Tags: laravel, json, jsonobject, livewire

Tengo un problema consumiendo una api, resulta que al llamarla en ciertos casos me entrega el client y su id porque este existe precisamente, pero en otros casos el client simplemente no existe, no viene en la data de la api (no sale el client ni sus valores).

Tengo mi codigo como muestro en la imagen, y por consecuencia me arroja ese error, lo que intento hacer no me resulta, precisamente lo que busco es no mostrar este ErrorException. Este codigo fue de otra prueba en el cual utilizo una variable de por medio, pero tampoco logro una solucion... Me gustaria ver como modificarlo, probe poniendo `if(array_key_exists(["items"][0]["client"]["id"], $response))` pero tampoco me sirve o funciona

```
if(array_key_exists("items", $response))
{
$vienedata = $response["items"][0]["client"]["id"];
if ($vienedata !== null)
$this->customerjson = $response["items"][0]["client"]["id"];
}else{
session()->flash('message', 'No existe un registro de cliente');
}
```

Esta es la data que en algunos casos llega

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Raro que el mensaje de error que muestras dice otra cosa de lo que planteas como el problema. ¿Tenés una propiedad `$customerjson` en esa clase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de esto:

```php
if(array_key_exists("items", $response))
```

por esto:

```php
if(array_key_exists("items", $response) and isset($response["items"][0]["client"]["id"]) and $response["items"][0]["client"]["id"] !== null)
```

[isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) evaluará si existe o no ese valor dentro del array y te saltarás el error espero.